# autoconf/automake/libtool - how to undefine PACKAGE_NAME, PACKAGE_TARNAME, PACKAGE_VERSION and so on

Tags: autoconf, automake, libtool

Build log:

```
20:10:36 make[3]: Entering directory `/home/ubuntu/build/ColossusCoinXT/distsrc-i686-pc-linux-gnu/src/minizip'
20:10:36 /bin/bash ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -m32 -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"minizip\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"minizip\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"1.2.8\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"minizip\ 1.2.8\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"bugzilla.redhat.com\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"minizip\" -DVERSION=\"1.2.8\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -I.  -I./../.. -I/home/ubuntu/build/ColossusCoinXT/depends/i686-pc-linux-gnu/share/../include/   -pipe -O2 -O2 -g -c -o ioapi.lo ioapi.c  
20:10:36 libtool: compile:  gcc -m32 -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"minizip\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"minizip\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"1.2.8\" "-DPACKAGE_STRING=\"minizip 1.2.8\"" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"bugzilla.redhat.com\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"minizip\" -DVERSION=\"1.2.8\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -I. -I./../.. -I/home/ubuntu/build/ColossusCoinXT/depends/i686-pc-linux-gnu/share/../include/ -pipe -O2 -O2 -g -c ioapi.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o ioapi.o
20:10:36 gcc: error: 1.2.8": No such file or directory
```

Problem is on the 3rd line: `"-DPACKAGE_STRING=\"minizip 1.2.8\""`, compiler interprets this define as two different arguments, due to space. I'm looking for workaround, the easiest way seems undefine these AC_INIT preprocessor symbols, but I didn't find a way to do this.

configure.ac:

```
AC_INIT([minizip], [1.2.8], [bugzilla.redhat.com])
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([minizip.c])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([no-define foreign])
LT_INIT
...
```

Looking for quick workaround, thank you!

Comment: Some older projects, notably binutils and GCC, use the old form of `AC_INIT` that only required the name of a file in the source directory. The manual explains that it was equivalent to `AC_INIT` (no arguments), followed by `AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([filename])`. This actually still works as far as I can tell. You might need to define the macros `AC_PACKAGE_NAME`, `AC_PACKAGE_VERSION`, and some others and use `AC_SUBST([PACKAGE_NAME], [AC_PACKAGE_NAME])` and such for Automake/Libtool. For more info, you'll want to look at the private macro `_AC_INIT_PACKAGE` in /usr/share/autoconf/autoconf/general.m4.

Comment: It is more work than your solution, and it may break at some point, which is why I didn't post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

For now I use next workaround:

```
AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS([quickfix], [sed -i 's/minizip\\\ 1.2.8/minizip-1.2.8/g' Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

Please post better solution if you know.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at your build output:

- As make prints it, the libtool command line as called by make contains `-DPACKAGE_STRING=\"minizip\ 1.2.8\"` which is a good way to pass an argument containg a space character on the shell.
- As libtool prints it, the gcc compile command as called by libtool contains `"-DPACKAGE_STRING=\"minizip 1.2.8\""` which is another good way to pass an argument containing a space character on the command line.

No mistakes to be found there yet.

However, the error message `gcc` prints suggests that the `gcc` command eventually called actually differs from what `libtool` prints as the command.

This leaves two possibilities:

- The `libtool` script your build uses is broken and calls `gcc` in a different way than the way it prints. You could try running `make distclean` and re-running `autoreconf` and `configure` to rebuild the minizip buildsystem from scratch, which includes the `libtool` script.
- The `libtool` script calls `gcc` command properly, but the `gcc` command is a wrapper around the actual gcc, and that wrapper passes its arguments to the actual `gcc` improperly, which in turn chokes on the improper arguments. One example of a software package wrapping `gcc` is `ccache`, but there are others.

  One way to examine this would be running `which gcc` in a shell and then analyzing the result: which package it belongs to, whether it is redirected using alternatives, etc. There might be an updated version of this software with the quoting bug fixed.

The minizip source tree itself is fine (tested on Debian 10):

```
[user@host ~]$ git clone https://github.com/madler/zlib.git
[…]
[user@host ~]$ cd zlib/contrib/minizip
[user@host minizip]$ git checkout -b minizip-1.2.8 v1.2.8
[…]
[user@host minizip]$ autoreconf -vis .
[…]
[user@host minizip]$ ./configure --prefix=$PWD/_i
[…]
[user@host minizip]$ make
/bin/bash ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"minizip\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"minizip\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"1.2.8\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"minizip\ 1.2.8\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"bugzilla.redhat.com\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"minizip\" -DVERSION=\"1.2.8\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -I.  -I./../..   -g -O2 -MT ioapi.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/ioapi.Tpo -c -o ioapi.lo ioapi.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"minizip\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"minizip\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"1.2.8\" "-DPACKAGE_STRING=\"minizip 1.2.8\"" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"bugzilla.redhat.com\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"minizip\" -DVERSION=\"1.2.8\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -I. -I./../.. -g -O2 -MT ioapi.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/ioapi.Tpo -c ioapi.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/ioapi.o
libtool: compile:  gcc -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"minizip\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"minizip\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"1.2.8\" "-DPACKAGE_STRING=\"minizip 1.2.8\"" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"bugzilla.redhat.com\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"minizip\" -DVERSION=\"1.2.8\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -I. -I./../.. -g -O2 -MT ioapi.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/ioapi.Tpo -c ioapi.c -o ioapi.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/ioapi.Tpo .deps/ioapi.Plo
[…]
libtool: link: gcc -shared  -fPIC -DPIC  .libs/ioapi.o .libs/mztools.o .libs/unzip.o .libs/zip.o   -L./../.. -lz  -g -O2   -Wl,-soname -Wl,libminizip.so.1 -o .libs/libminizip.so.1.0.0
libtool: link: (cd ".libs" && rm -f "libminizip.so.1" && ln -s "libminizip.so.1.0.0" "libminizip.so.1")
libtool: link: (cd ".libs" && rm -f "libminizip.so" && ln -s "libminizip.so.1.0.0" "libminizip.so")
libtool: link: ar cru .libs/libminizip.a  ioapi.o mztools.o unzip.o zip.o
ar: `u' modifier ignored since `D' is the default (see `U')
libtool: link: ranlib .libs/libminizip.a
libtool: link: ( cd ".libs" && rm -f "libminizip.la" && ln -s "../libminizip.la" "libminizip.la" )
[user@host minizip]$ _
```